# Infer one of generic types from function argument

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example. `fetchItems` function returns response or response body depending on passed `onlyBody` argument which defaults to `true`.

```js
interface HttpResponse<T> {
  body: T
}

function fetchItems<T, B extends boolean>(url: string, onlyBody: B = true as B) {
  return Promise
    .resolve({body: 'some data'} as any)
    .then<B extends true ? T : HttpResponse<T>>(res => onlyBody ? res.body : res);
}
```

If both generic types are passed the function works as expected

```js
const a = fetchItems<string, false>('url', false) // Promise<HttpResponse<string>>
const b = fetchItems<string, true>('url', true)   // Promise<string>
const c = fetchItems<string, true>('url')         // Promise<string>
```

I'd like to drop requirement of passing `B` type as it is redundant in relation to `onlyBody` parameter. But when `B` type is not explictly passed, ts compiler complains about it (Expected 2 type arguments but got 1).

```js
const e = fetchItems<string>('url', false);        // would want Promise<HttpResponse<string>>
const f = fetchItems<string>('url', true)          // would want Promise<string>
const g = fetchItems<string>('url')                // would want Promise<string>
```

I tried to change fucntion signature into:

```js
function fetchItems<T, B extends boolean = true>(url: string, onlyBody: B = true as B) {
```

but then there is an error in `e` example: `Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'true | undefined'`

Is there any way to alter function signature so that e, f, g examples will work the same as a, b, c ? 
demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ydkmzk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem you're facing is that TypeScript does not support [partial type parameter inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  Either you must manually specify all type parameters (except for ones with defaults), or you let the compiler infer all type parameters, but you cannot specify some and let the compiler infer the rest.

Using overloads instead of generic type parameters, as shown in [@Nenad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57589352/2887218) is one way around this for types like `boolean` with a small number of possible values.  The issue mentioned in the comments with a `boolean` parameter (instead of a `true` or `false` one) can be solved by adding another overload, like this:

```
function fetchItems<T>(
  url: string,
  onlyBody: false
): Promise<HttpResponse<T>>;
function fetchItems<T>(url: string, onlyBody?: true): Promise<T>;

// add this overload
function fetchItems<T>(
  url: string,
  onlyBody: boolean
): Promise<T | HttpResponse<T>>;

function fetchItems<T>(url: string, onlyBody: boolean = true) {
  return Promise.resolve({ body: "some data" } as any).then(
    res => (onlyBody ? res.body : res)
  );
}

const a = fetchItems<string>("url", false); // Promise<HttpResponse<string>>
const b = fetchItems<string>("url", true); // Promise<string>
const c = fetchItems<string>("url"); // Promise<string>
const d = fetchItems<string>("url", Math.random() < 0.5); 
// Promise<string|HttpResponse<string>>
```

I know of two other workarounds, which I've been calling Currying and Dummying:

---

The "Currying" workaround splits your single generic function of two type parameters into two [curried functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying]) of one type parameter each.  One you specify, the other you infer.  Like this:

```
const fetchItems = <T>() => <B extends boolean = true>(
  url: string,
  onlyBody: B = true as B
) => {
  return Promise.resolve({ body: "some data" } as any).then<
    B extends true ? T : HttpResponse<T>
  >(res => (onlyBody ? res.body : res));
};
```

And you call it like this:

```
const a = fetchItems<string>()("url", false); // Promise<HttpResponse<string>>
const b = fetchItems<string>()("url", true); // Promise<string>
const c = fetchItems<string>()("url"); // Promise<string>
const d = fetchItems<string>()("url", Math.random() < 0.5); 
// Promise<string|HttpResponse<string>>
```

Or, since all of those use `fetchItems<string>()`, you can save that to its own function and use it, for a bit less redundancy:

```
const fetchItemsString = fetchItems<string>();
const e = fetchItemsString("url", false); // Promise<HttpResponse<string>>
const f = fetchItemsString("url", true); // Promise<string>
const g = fetchItemsString("url"); // Promise<string>
const h = fetchItemsString("url", Math.random() < 0.5); 
// Promise<string|HttpResponse<string>>
```

---

The "Dummying" workaround lets the compiler infer all the parameter types, even the ones you want to specify manually.  It does this by having the function take dummy parameters of the types you would normally specify manually; the function ignores the dummy parameters:

```
function fetchItems<T, B extends boolean = true>(
  dummyT: T,
  url: string,
  onlyBody: B = true as B
) {
  return Promise.resolve({ body: "some data" } as any).then<
    B extends true ? T : HttpResponse<T>
  >(res => (onlyBody ? res.body : res));
}

const a = fetchItems("dummy", "url", false); // Promise<HttpResponse<string>>
const b = fetchItems("dummy", "url", true); // Promise<string>
const c = fetchItems("dummy", "url"); // Promise<string>
const d = fetchItems("dummy", "url", Math.random() < 0.5); 
// Promise<string|HttpResponse<string>>
```

Since the dummy value is only for the benefit of the compiler and is unused at runtime, you can also use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to pretend you have an instance of the type instead of going through any trouble to create one:

```
const dummy = null! as string; // null at runtime, string at compile time

const e = fetchItems(dummy, "url", false); // Promise<HttpResponse<string>>
const f = fetchItems(dummy, "url", true); // Promise<string>
const g = fetchItems(dummy, "url"); // Promise<string>
const h = fetchItems(dummy, "url", Math.random() < 0.5); 
// Promise<string|HttpResponse<string>>
```

Of course it's pretty easy to get a `string` value, so there's not much point using `null! as string` instead of `"randomString"`, but for more complicated types it becomes more convenient to use the type assertion instead of trying to create a real instance that you'll just be throwing away.

---

Anyway, hope one of those works for you.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false#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-T8g3Z4w4TW5SVG7Q7Rhl44nPFTU4H9Zns0ozcgALI08w4s5sVIOOLIMjIAAMWIArHmY46i1tWrcsk9cu6DaPQwm1WJJAQZMgAMKuKDihhMDVJ3W-Ww6uodoWd0LICAAD0gIHUEKhZx1CMcgUBTVnOzWovB57hCKZGihPEgo0NuawomAaIFpiOL4PiECEsSkTkqkKDUrS9KMsyTIgGyHJciAZCBEw55Xjed7-pKFDyg82TPNO1CBI4AqniKHRgnKkq4jKEQ0YqKpaIIAgllqcDlnqfwzsCjhxFm4YWqQg7QU6E6ui8UlGgmO6+sw4kHhms4yXJOYRlAAxKbGI7SSJyApnCAYScGhntsZNYWcOHqGTZbB6emGlei51a1g2nLNrebYdl2vYDta+aWZ5wLji69FWZpIjaXuDn6QAyrOvmVs5AkZaWKD2WmSy5cCrm1vAlruYW5CqSlCVpcVWowPlfyVb41WmeZsVDg1-mhjZPidbY3WtNV9WYsNWm2b65jjXgk0+L19aNmFrbiO2nY9v2M1xrOSV0VOqVevOIiLlIK4ACI6OI4hbh80xlHMWV+RQ5qkde3J3kcJyPn+ZkQC+uxsA9T0UDwX2vhs77Ap+TDfiSyC-vCIMAWjwFgUwEFQfFsF4koBJErKyEUmhNJ0gyWOsuynLckRfJoxev23holG8DRTVna8TEOCxwoo+KXHSuTfH4HERUMulC17mJZUVn8WYQ49HC1kF5q1YpA3KRkvNuudc42bpSuOXgquQxr5paxj-XRvrLVejZdn7umVvq5rpqHcb827qWPnm-pntPd7JkbaFUAthFe3Rb7zs+Cdk5G4n3redbOogDoShKAAhFjIZ69nudMlqZngMAkjmiGZcLeImDACc8JVxAcsB1qpXu0sDhq09tvyTrVqO-Fzqnanc3+76HXBx7fccAPEeRnro-Fm1yBjbPPfz4vbkrx5c02UtW8qzvyB2yFTbR+FO2RftMUjwfIbJ2p07xpdQA)

Comment: Thanks, adding that overload you suggested solved the problem. Btw nice workarounds, never thought about using currying with generics, definitely gonna try it.

Answer (score 3):

Function overloads can do what you need:

```js
function fetchItems<T>(url: string, onlyBody: false): Promise<HttpResponse<T>>
function fetchItems<T>(url: string, onlyBody?: true): Promise<T>
function fetchItems<T>(url: string, onlyBody: boolean = true) {
  return Promise
    .resolve({body: 'some data'} as any)
    .then(res => onlyBody ? res.body : res);
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBJjABwEoQM6YD2IeEAPACoB8yA3gLABQyyARoQCYCeAXMhUwC+TJjACuIBGGDFkMCGAQALAJKQAtnkpUAFGKgAbPnjBRQAcwA0yYga4AhTrzlwDpAJR8AClELrgpGToWLgExIHUVKISUjIgcgrKahCa2nqGxqYW1rYOTgD8fKZiEJ7IPn4B5NTRktKy8oqqGlrU6UbIJmYgVjYgdo7cfOyEBhBw8QC8yMWldEwsUAr68RX+pAssyAB0S3ijAG4QOrTsQ8gA5PvqKBxwYHAXgshweC8gXO6bLNtgShAgHR7ZCTGi5QZcZD5ZB7bZnSF8PbuADcQhEjAQ4TAyBQ00aSRaZC6Fl0F30Bgu1ngblKyK29OQAHpGcgAO6EMQGDhsibYtZVIIYHD4IgkcjEnpUKIYrFyEEJJrJVIS8yk8mUmZQEruBkM5lsjlcnngcq+dbirKSpiYkjY8zy-HNFJaFVqwwXHW6r0sfXsznc1m802VQKuoA)

Solution with *conditional types* does not work due to TypeScript "design limitation" described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19360).

Comment: The problem with this solutions is that it doesn't allow to pass boolean arg as `onlyBody`. For example this usage: `function fetchUsers(onlyBody: boolean) {
  return fetchItems<string>('/users', onlyBody);
}` will result in error `Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'true | undefined'.` It could be solved by making overloads also for this function but such solution is messy if there is a lot of functions like this.

Comment: Yes, overloads seem to be only way. But you could put them only on top methods. You don't need them on everything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest alternative that I believe has much better readability and is more simple overall. Declare two methods instead of 1:

```
fetch<T>(url: string): Promise<HttpResponse<T>>
fetchBody<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
   return fetch(url).then(resp => resp.body)
}
```