# How to infer the return type of a generic callback function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm having issues inferring the type of a generic callback function. This is my code:

```js
import { FC, createElement, useState, useMemo, createContext as _context, useContext as _useContext } from 'react';

const createContext = <T>(useHook: (providerProps: T) => any) => {
  const ctx = _context({});

  /** Component with provider and initial values calling the hook passed. */
  const Provider: FC<T> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    const value = useHook(props as T);
    return createElement(ctx.Provider, { value }, children);
  };

  /** Hook will return the context from the provider. */
  const useContext = () => _useContext(ctx) as ReturnType<typeof useHook>;

  /** Function will return the provider and the assign the `displayName` given. */
  const createProvider = (displayName: string) => {
    Provider.displayName = displayName;
    return Provider;
  };

  return {
    useContext,
    createProvider,
  };
};

/** Context with the values to keep track across the app. */
const ctx = createContext<{ _theme: 'light' | 'dark' }>(({ _theme }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(_theme);
  return useMemo(() => ({ theme, setTheme }), [theme]);
});

/** Provider for the values of the theme of the app. */
export const AppThemeProvider = ctx.createProvider('AppThemeProvider');

const useAppTheme = () => {
  const { theme } = ctx.useContext();
}
```

I just want a cleaner way to create context without doing a provider and some hooks. The issue I'm having is that the return type is not being inferred in the `as ReturnType<typeof useHook>` line. It shows everything as any. and I would like to have the same type as what the useHook function returns.

In the hook useAppTheme the line `const { theme } = ctx.useContext();` theme type is of type any but it should be of type `'light' | 'dark'`

Can somebody help me? Pls.

Thanks!

Comment: [Please replace or supplement images of code or errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)  There's no `systemTheme` in the code you included as plaintext, and I can't copy from an image into my IDE to test anything.

Comment: It looks like you explicitly annotated the return type of `useHook` as `any`, so that's what its return type is.  If you want to do something else, maybe have it generic in the return type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnXMxW), but without a plaintext [mre] that demonstrates exactly what you mean by "everything" in "infers everything as any" I can't tell if that completely solves your problem or only partially solves your problem. (or maybe doesn't do anything at all.)

Comment: Hi @jcalz thank you to look at it. Sadly that didn't solve my problem because in that case I would need to declare the return type as the second type when calling the `createContext` function, I would like to fully infer the return value of that `useHook` callback hook and assign it to the return value of the type below. I tried returning unknown or never but it does not work either. I changed the image to text so you can easily copy/paste it

Comment: So does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvYyMm) work for you?  You have to have a generic type parameter like `R`; there's no way to infer otherwise.  If you have two type parameters and need to specify one and infer the other then you have to work around TS's limitations in that area (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/57589098/2887218 ) such as using currying.

Comment: @jcalz you're the best of the world, I don't like the `()(props => ...)` to call the function but this is a solution!! Thanks, I'll take a look to currying if I see anything I can do. Thanks again!

Comment: So shall I write that up as an answer?  Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem completely. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your version you are explicitly annotating the return type of the `useHook` parameter to be `any`, so that's what the compiler sees.  If you want to be able to narrow that down based on the return type of the actual callback value passed in as `useHook`, then you will need to make `createContext` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that type also, something like:

```
const createContext = <T, R>(useHook: (providerProps: T) => R) => ...
```

and then use `R` instead of `ReturnType<typeof useHook>` inside the implementation.

---

But you don't want to *manually specify* both `T` and `R`.  You want to manually specify `T` but let the compiler infer `R`, and unfortunately this is not currently supported in TypeScript.  Either the compiler will try to infer all the type parameters, or you have to manually specify all of them.  There is no "partial type parameter inference" as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  So you'll need to work around it.

There are two workarounds I can think of.

---

The first is to let the compiler infer both `T` and `R` by manually [annotating the callback parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) instead of specifying the type parameter directly:

```
const ctx = createContext(({ _theme }: { _theme: 'light' | 'dark' }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(_theme);
  return useMemo(() => ({ theme, setTheme }), [theme]);
});
```

This is the same amount of work for the caller of `createContext` more or less, but now the compiler can use type inference for both `T` and `R` and everything works out well:

```
ctx.useContext().theme // "light" | "dark"
```

I like this method because it's fairly natural, but if you really want someone to write `createContext<{ _theme: 'light' | 'dark' }>(...)` then read on.

---

The other workaround is to use [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) so that instead of a function of two type parameters, you have a function of one type parameter that returns another function of one type parameter:

```
const createContext = <T>() => <R>(useHook: (providerProps: T) => R) => ...
```

Now you have one function where you can manually specify `T` and another function where the compiler can infer `R`:

```
const ctx = createContext<{ _theme: 'light' | 'dark' }>()(({ _theme }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(_theme);
  return useMemo(() => ({ theme, setTheme }), [theme]);
});

ctx.useContext().theme // "light" | "dark"
```

The downside of this is the weird construction `foo<T>()(x, y, z)` instead of `foo<T>(x, y, z)`.  But it does work well.  It's up to you which of these workarounds fits your needs best.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMQMIBo4GMoFMCGMuAogDa4i4B2MmArgM64DKMhu9TAshRJjgSKoINXAA94+BnAD6WEUQmdcw0RLhTZjFQvHwAvnABmUCCDgByPPiwwLAbgBQjqvkoMwN3HACCVKhBsRIjOcNgiDPAC7KqK8AC8cAA8ACqYAEoAfAAU2gASEBAA1gBccNlgpgBuwAAmuFAACqZgDGUpAJRw8Zlw6V09IWFh8lSR2DBi3bKjcdkI+h1OjsNwAPQAVBtwwuAi1PAA7sAwABZwlRA19VAaVLVwwFQnwPikcFVvdLjSWG+kTwA5nAzt5ToUihcpExagA6OAbNYrYajcbNK51BplNCpXqJebYU7AUi1PBUTCwymXVpwRbdXoIZGrVHwT6kb7TfIQiotaSaTpOVZhPAwOhQKjYaxEMgUA7ZWxiWHo64NTBINkc-T8IkkslLJm05arTbbArFODHUjvEViiWg8JqeAmMwg07eS4qqDwxEGllwbSxPTTbIDXoyAO6CTyyZdTTpI3DE0oOhUWzAEQW4nW3Ci8Wu93VTG3fD3fMaBgMYCAu1uuAAA1qwA8pHwAE8AHJuXB1uCA4BVajepHMiJRKW4ZVF4ON5ttzuUMqRKBA0NDIWTm6wmdgFsdrvTbe7+e4QVCm15jcNU9hfQJ4U521r1YRx3oA0jceXqBv1a35F-5Ek0DdRjjOMsNR+EEIDgIpcFwMAQSgGxIRsUwKzLfAwDAIdkT9BVpmiIRIxgbICRkUFKFpMokHIt0F0sAFAVOOw4AAH0sWp8CgIoLFpVdGRHMZ4AAbQojg4CYGAUjo3AAF1OSYVh2GyWjZX1VZzwlbQeBACBSNXAkxMwSTpNlPjMFEmTZPUviEwVWEXzmDpYTE9Y1jgAAiRjmI8tjPM47iPNCdYtjgL9jGgcCvkgiAjDLVzYowrCcLCcRIFgB1xh8LDTMocLEnswiJ0LG5sgsbKwFy4qMRuCx9Vw0d-SYCqquDfjfUapBXMMArJgcphgJImz9EcEaXC7DwvB2MUoFbNc8PHQbplxEN6WSLJciYM1SnKD0i3RVp2lXfo1oElFGvwxI5GI+ZFjvELtl2SAqAOTMwL2m47geJ4XjeD5ot+f4gTLcFzU8CtcDhBFh3OoSwpKrEUFQXFgyQLAdVJagKSpXk+NO99MtZaKFNwbaeQgGl+RsjSHzzIqZUoGho0VL81X+9lvC1QliUxqhqcNYKwiTbbMytOBNLLWYg2dcx7Q+hoUth8ZHKDfFV3DAaboVWNpHjQWHuTVMYHTCVLWzXMawLGqGi+jCKyrS360POcux7PsByoRWRguz8EdufFnb3eilxXfGhXh62vUD48DybHcXcoa9hglr8k4AmmLafYYVaUAmitZg0-xvBMgOIt7zntCDpBgaDYPgxDkI0HAIHQ+1MOw6GGrhy7JUEHRHSSGixLKCxvJY9iLACnjaRyDpSKHmS8cGM7vbhyzZWMnMqvkxJtCUogVLE-mJe03h9LWwyZM3qTF8WCyxOs087uC+yc6GlzF7WdyvKrHy-I8qeQVAKhXCkYSKlcAZwESvaBKcU27JU7qlMQ6UoiNRajJfKExFT5z9mVdBsovx1Tso1bQ+DKJqzDkreAXVb4ET6m-EMT9nD6CAA)